# Vagrant, only download packages once instead of for every project in linux

Tags: linux, networking, package, vagrant, sudo

I'm a complete Linux novice **trying** to convert from good ole windows(mmm..) so go easy my hearts in the right place!

I'm using vagrant to create a Ubuntu environment

My host folder structure is currently

```
- root
-- VagrantFile
-- .vagrant [folder]
-- public [folder]
--- Project1 [folder]
--- Project2 [folder] and so on
```

Following below is my basic vagrant config.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |c|
  c.vm.box = "precise32"
  c.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box"
  c.vm.network = :private_network, ip:"192.168.33.10"
  c.vm.synced_folder "./public", "/var/www/"
end
```

How would I go about installing packages such as `composer,laravel,npm,nodejs,gulp` etc in a way that means I wouldnt have to download them again and can install in each project as required.

**I want them to be retained on the host in say a "packages" directory but accessible from within the VM's cli** meaning if I destroy the VM I can `vagrant up` another VM and have all the packages ready to use without redownloading.

If that made sense and is possible, can someone advise a method of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this plugin, which handles this for you: https://github.com/fgrehm/vagrant-cachier